# Need to Sync Oracle DB table data with mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, cron

I have a table with some data in oracle which i want to sync with mysql table once in a day, like a cron job.

Is there any tool available which i can use as a cron job in Linux?.

Thanks,

Comment: How is this different than http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109339/how-to-copy-a-oracle-db-table-with-mysql-db-table

Comment: @RickJames This question and the one you linked to are both closure for `shopping list` request. Questions asking on tools to use are generally frowned upon, because the tool you say can work today may not be around in two years, or a better one is released.

Comment: @ShawnMelton - I don't understand.  Sure, the tool may vanish, but OP needs a solution today, and the solution is complex enough to need a "tool".  Sure, it would be nice if questions & answers are still valid years from now; but the product is likely to change, thereby obviating both the answer and the question.  I link to sites (esp, my own) when an answer is too long or complex to type into this limited window.  I get criticized for that, even though I believe it helps the OP.